# UIScrollview not adding buttons

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have defined a uiscrollview and used a for loop to add buttons to it, but whenever I run the program, I come up with a blank screen.
Here is my viewDidLoad, this is all the code i have relating to this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1000)];
    scrollView.hidden = NO;
    names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Excavations",@"Concrete",@"Framing",@"Insulation",@"Drywall",@"Finish Carpentry",@"Paint",@"Electrical",@"HVAC",@"Plumbing",@"Roofing",@"Tile",@"Doors",@"Windows",@"Flooring",@"Countertops",@"Landscape",@"Hardscape", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50*i, 320, 50);
        button.tag = i;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(NewView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.titleLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:i];
        button.hidden= NO;
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
    }

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the UIScrollView to your view. Try

```
...
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1000)];
scrollView.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
...
```

Comment: That was it. I tried [self addSubview] but it didnt work. I guess I need to specify the view part of self.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up the type for button manually, or just initialize with it:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Edit: you also forgot to add your scrollview to main view

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```